# Python Requests - Get Server IP

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-requests, ip

I'm making a small tool that tests CDN performance and would like to check where the response comes from. I thought of getting the host's IP and then using one of the geolocation API's on github to check the country.

I've tried doing so with

```
import socket
...
raw._fp.fp._sock.getpeername()
```

...however that only works when i use `stream=True` for the request and that in turn breaks the tool's functionality.
Is there any other option to get the server ip with requests or in a completely different way?

Comment: It's always better to have minimal working example, so they don't have to start from scratch to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `socket.gethostbyname()` function from Python's socket library should solve your problem. You can check it out in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
import socket
url="cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
print("IP:",socket.gethostbyname(url))
```

All you need to do is pass the url to `socket.gethostbyname()` and it will do the rest. Just make sure to remove the `http://` before the URL because that will trip it up.

Comment: This only appears to be working with the extension stripped, so for instance when testing cloudflare.com/file... i would need to remove 'file...'. But isn't there a chance that 'cloudflare.com' and 'cloudflare.com/file...' are delivered from two different servers, to reduce the time for content delivery`?

Comment: There is definitely a chance. However, I'd imagine that Cloudflare would not want you to know that. They most likely use a system of load balancers that queries the best server based on location and file availability. I don't think that you would be able to query these servers directly though. The best you could do is test their front-facing CDN interface.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Akilan's solution to give the IP address of a different host that I was using. `socket.gethostbyname()` and `getpeername()` were not working for me. They are not even available. His solution did open the door.

However, navigating the socket object, I did find this:

`socket.getaddrinfo('host name', 443)[0][4][0]`

I wrapped this in a try/except block.

Maybe there is a prettier way.